# How can I keep Apache stopped on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, wamp, lamp, ubuntu-10.10

Actually, I want something like WAMP (for Windows). The Apache service should be always stopped. Whenever I need it to be running, I go to the Start Menu and turn it on. Is there a way to make it possible on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Remove apache "autostart" from runlevels with the following:

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove
```

Make a script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

gksudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Make it runnable

```
chmod 0755 apache-starter-shell-script-name
```

And run it when you want to start apache.

Comment: Update command should read like this `sudo update-rc.d apache2 remove`.

Comment: sorry, I mixed it up with 'defaults'. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more a serverfault.com question.

Nevertheless you could modify your runlevel configuration (Ubuntu uses upstart instead of init) and then start apache manually from the console when you need it.

Unfortunately I don't know the upstart configuration options by mind but I think some googling for it's configuration should help you.

Edit: Maybe Boot-Up Manager is what you need (http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html) - I don't use Ubuntu as desktop.

Edit2: Try

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
```